# Stop submitting form unless all fields are filled in

Tags: angularjs

How do i validate a form in angular? Coz i have the below form which uses https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload where all the fields are required.

The problem is when i hit submit it shows a tip saying the field is required but the form gets submitted. i want to stop submitting unless all the fields are filled in.

And how do i allow the user to select only images from the profile input? coz when although i add `ng-accept="image/*"` is not working

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
 <input type="text" ng-model="name" required>
 <input type="text" ng-model="age" required>
 <input type="text" ng-model="title" required> 
 <input type="file" name="profile_pic" ng-file-select="onFileSelect" required>
 <input type="file" name="document" ng-file-select="onFileSelect2" required>
 <input type='button' ng-click='onFormSubmit(onFileSelect,onFileSelect)' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Angular

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngFileUpload']);

var MyCtrl = [ '$scope', 'Upload', function($scope, Upload) {
  $scope.onFileSelect = function(file) {

Upload.upload({
    url: 'api/upload-data.php', 
    method: 'POST',
    file: file,
    data: {
        'name': $scope.name,
        'age' : $scope.age ,
        'title' : $scope.title ,


    }
})

  };
}];
```

Comment: Give a name to your form (let's say "myForm"), give a name to each of its inputs, and use `<button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a name to your form (so you can reference it), change your ng-click on button to ng-submit on the form itself, and change the submit into a button element with type="submit" + ng-disabled if the form is invalid

```
<form name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" ng-submit="onFormSubmit(onFileSelect,onFileSelect)" >
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" required>
    <input type="text" ng-model="age" required>
    <input type="text" ng-model="title" required> 
    <input type="file" name="profile_pic" ng-file-select="onFileSelect" required>
    <input type="file" name="document" ng-file-select="onFileSelect2" required>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: ng-click on the button is fine, too. But the button should be a submit button, as you're correctly doing in your answer.

Comment: Yeah, ng-click is generally ok if you don't want to submit forms using the enter key - but for example in login forms you want to enable pressing enter to submit the form after entering username + password, which won't work with ng-click EDIT: Nevermind, ng-click is fine!

Comment: That would work fine with ng-click, too. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

Comment: Oh, you're actually right - disregard my earlier comment!